# Python Regular Expression to Remove Unwanted Parts of URL

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

So I have these URLs that keep changing:

```
http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNFcQAQ4S3H5xUuU4N-LoM2I9tLxJg&url=http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/going-out-guide/wp/2013/11/08/dallas-buyers-club-thor-the-dark-world-and-other-new-movies-reviewed/
```

But I want to strip off the changing first part and just get left with the:

```
http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/going-out-guide/wp/2013/11/08/dallas-buyers-club-thor-the-dark-world-and-other-new-movies-reviewed/
```

What regular expression would I use to remove everything up to that?

I can't use "startswith()" because the "usg" numbers change in that URL.

Comment: What is wrong with [`urlparse.parse_qs()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs)

Comment: @MartijnPieters are you going to put that as an answer... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the right tool for the job; parse a query string using the [`urlparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html):

```
import urlparse

qs = urlparse.urlsplit(inputurl).query
url = urlparse.parse_qs(qs).get('url', [None])[0]
```

This sets `url` to `None` if there was no `url=` element in the url query string, the URL value otherwise.

Demo:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> inputurl = 'http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNFcQAQ4S3H5xUuU4N-LoM2I9tLxJg&url=http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/going-out-guide/wp/2013/11/08/dallas-buyers-club-thor-the-dark-world-and-other-new-movies-reviewed/'
>>> qs = urlparse.urlsplit(inputurl).query
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(qs).get('url', [None])[0]
'http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/going-out-guide/wp/2013/11/08/dallas-buyers-club-thor-the-dark-world-and-other-new-movies-reviewed/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
print data.split("&url=", 1)[1].split("&", 1)[0]
```

**Sample Run**

```
data = "http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNFcQAQ4S3H5xUuU4N-
LoM2I9tLxJg&url=http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/going-out-guide/wp/2013/
11/08/dallas-buyers-club-thor-the-dark-world-and-other-new-movies-reviewed/"
print data.split("&url=", 1)[1].split("&", 1)[0]
```

**Output**

```
http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/going-out-guide/wp/2013/11/08/dallas-buyers-club-thor-the-dark-world-and-other-new-movies-reviewed/
```

Comment: Apart from the fact there's a better solution -  you might also wish to either limit the times that split bothers splitting, or use partition

Comment: @JonClements Updated my answer to limit the splitting. Please check now

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine:

```
url = "http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNFcQAQ4S3H5xUuU4N-
LoM2I9tLxJg&url=http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/going-out-guide/wp/2013/
11/08/dallas-buyers-club-thor-the-dark-world-and-other-new-movies-reviewed/"

In [148]: url.split('&url=')[1]
Out[148]: 'http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/going-out-guide/wp/2013/11/08/dallas-buyers-club-thor-the-dark-world-and-other-new-movies-reviewed/'
```

I'd use `urlparse.parse_qs(url)` as @MartijnPieters mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that what is to the right of "&url=" is *not* a url.  It is a *url-encoded url*.  So, for example, if the original url contained "&", this would contain "%26".  Using it without decoding would work for many urls but in general is not guaranteed to.

As Martjin suggested, this will always work correctly:

```
import urlparse
data = "http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNFcQAQ4S3H5xUuU4N-LoM2I9tLxJg&url=http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/going-out-guide/wp/2013/11/08/dallas-buyers-club-thor-the-dark-world-and-other-new-movies-reviewed/"
o = urlparse.urlparse(data)
q = urlparse.parse_qs(o.query)
print q['url']
```